# how can I get post data in Kohana 3 controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, post, kohana, kohana-3

I've got a view with a form, so when user submits it - could anyone give me a link or a simple example of code
Documentation and tutorials for Kohana 3 are so 
 poor against CI .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to access post data in Kohana

```
$username = Arr::get($_POST, 'username', 'default_username');
```

Answer (score 38):

In Kohana 3.1 you should use Request->post():

```
Request::current()->post()
```

or if in your controller:

```
$this->request->post()
```

Since Kohana is HMVC, you can call sub-requests with dedicated post data, so using the superglobal $_POST is discouraged, since it's not unique to the request.

Comment: Also you can use `$this->request->post($key)` to get `$_POST[$key]` if exists

Comment: Although it isn't relevant to this question, I came here looking for request data in general regarding Kohana, and I discovered that `$this->request->query()` is the GET version of `post()` and just thought I'd mention it for anyone in my situation. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
       function action_add()
   {
    $tpl =& $this->template;

    // Add companies
    $company_orm = ORM::factory('company');
    $company_orm->values($_POST);

    if ( $company_orm->check() )  //Validation Check
    {
        if ( $company_orm->save() )
        {
            // Inserting data
        }
        else
        {

            // Error
        }
    }
    else
    {
            // Validation Failed
    }

}
```

Small Example. You can implement all the validations in the model using protected.

Thank you